# FME Data migration for Feature class with Attachments

Tags: fme-form

I want to migrate data from one point feature class to another point feature class in same Database schema using FME job.  I can easily do this task without using any transformers. 
But now both point feature classes (reader and writer) has attachment tables. Attachment table has created by using arc catalog. The feature class and its attachment table have some relations. 
Can anyone please let me know how i can migrate data for attachment tables while I do data migration between feature classes?

Answer (score 1):

This might be accomplished easier with a Python script using ArcPy.  However, you could create an FME Workspace to create the Match Table independent of using the Generate Attachment Match Table Geoprocessing tool, but I'm not entirely sure if Arc makes more than one table here.

To create an ArcPy script you can export a model from [ModelBuilder](http://video.esri.com/watch/663/getting-started-with-modelbuilder) using Model => Export => To Python Script.  Creating the model should be fairly easy:  Insert => Add Data or Tool... and select your data.  Then use that same menu to add System Toolboxes => Data Management Tools => Attachments => Generate Attachment Match Table.

To create the table from FME you'll add your reader(s) then you'll want to use the [Matcher](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/Default.htm#Transformers/matcher.htm) transformer to match your data together based on your Selected Attributes.  Then pass the Match ID Output Attribute along with the ObjectIDs to a writer for the Match Table.  UNfortunately I don't know the naming scheme for these Match Tables.  You'll want to name the table appropriately so Arc recognizes it.